# Prevent Duplicate Data in SQLite Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm using Sqlite to save a google account after log in, I want to prevent duplicate when I click on button Save twice. I've searched here and used `insertWithOnConflict` but still not working. I think because my ID is auto increment. So how should I do?

**DBHelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "Account";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "User";
private static final String ID = "Id";
private static final String Name = "name";
private static final String Email = "email";
private static final String Avatar = "avatar";
private static final String UserId = "userid";
private static final String TokenId = "tokenid";

private String SQLQuery = "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_NAME+" ("+
        ID +" integer primary key, "+
        Name + " TEXT, "+
        Email + " TEXT, "+
        Avatar + " TEXT, "+
        UserId + " TEXT, "+
        TokenId + " TEXT)";


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLQuery);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
}

public void addUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Name, user.getmName());
    values.put(Email, user.getmEmail());
    values.put(Avatar, user.getmAvatar());
    values.put(UserId, user.getmUserID());
    values.put(TokenId, user.getmTokenID());

    db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, null, values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before preventing duplicate data, you have to define "uniqueness". In your case, I would guess `email`.
Even though you inserted data with `insertWithOnConflict`, when creating the table, you did NOT specify which column was `UNIQUE`. By default, it would be your autoincremented primary key, so every recorded inserted were a new one.
An example might be like (on `email` column):

```
private String SQLQuery = "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_NAME+" ("+
        ID +" integer primary key, "+
        Name + " TEXT, "+
        Email + " TEXT UNIQUE, "+
        Avatar + " TEXT, "+
        UserId + " TEXT, "+
        TokenId + " TEXT)";
```

Answer (score 0):

The first resolve, you can use `SELECT`, check if a row is exist in database then you will use `UPDATE` query to edit data in database. Opposite, you will use `INSERT` to insert data to database. The second resolve, you can use some libraries SQLite e.g. DBFlow, GreenDAO, etc. then use `.save` method with the same function.